# Show previous posts in WordPress (older than the current post)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on my single.php template and would like to show 3 previous post in my sidebar, but it should only display the "parent/previous" posts, which are older than the current post

This is my code so far:

```
                <?php

                $args = array(
                    'post_parent' => '$post->ID',
                    'posts_per_page' => '3',
                    );
                $query = new WP_Query ($args);

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php
                    echo '<div class="sidebar--parent-post">';
                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                            echo '<p class="sidebar--parent-title">' . the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') .'<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
                            echo '<p class="sidebar--parent-excerpt">' . excerpt('10') . '</p>';

                        endwhile;
                    echo '</div>';
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                else :

                    // nothing

                endif; ?>
```

My problem is:

This code always shows the recent posts and the post itself. I want to exclude the current post and only show posts, which are "older or below" the current post.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: You can use the new Date Parameters to filter your query. See documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: I've already looked up the docs for the date parameters, but I have no clue, how I can make use of it for my case :-(